# Understanding CS50 runoff vote() and tabulate() functions

Tags: c, cs50

I just did the runoff problem from cs50 lecture 3 But i m still not quite sure how the vote and tabulate function calls are working.
i've tried breaking down the function in parts and i understood around 60% of it but still not sure.
Like the parts where the 2D array is linking or working under the candidates class. how does the voter and rank variables work for preferences array? why assign them i instead of increment 1 to the votes or preferences[i][j].

can someone please break it down to me if possible?

i'd really appreciate it.

```
// Record preference if vote is valid
bool vote(int voter, int rank, string name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0)
        {
            preferences[voter][rank] = i;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Tabulate votes for non-eliminated candidates
void tabulate(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            int vote = preferences[i][j];
            if (!candidates[vote].eliminated)
            {
                candidates[vote].votes += 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: What is the "runoff problem from cs50 lecture 3"?  What is the 60% you *do* understand?

Comment: Where is `preferences` coming from?

Comment: There is a community for cs50, see https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/42209/pset3-runoff-tabulate-multiple-candidates?rq=1